# Convert jlist selection into a string

Tags: java, jlist

I am trying to figure out how to get the program to create a text string based on which item in a jlist is selected.  At first I tried

```
ListModel custTypetxt = custType.getModel();
System.out.println(custTypetxt);
```

but that just gave me..

```
customerInfoUI$3@1820dda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the selection from the list first. Call
`custType.getSelectedValue()`
(or `getSelectedValues()` for multiple selections). That will return the selected object. The you can get the string from the object any way you want (like `toString()` if it has been properly implemented by the class).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting the right object so you need to create a toString() method in the customerInfoUI class.

```
 public String toString(){
    return "String that describes my object";
 }
```

Then your code will print whatever you return from the toString method. The default implementation of toString in the Object class returns **`<classname>` @ hascode** which is what you are seeing when you run the code.